# ¿Como puedo mandar un archivo por un socket?

Tags: python, socket

Estoy haciendo un pequeño chat con sockets en python, estoy intentando hacer que se puedan mandar archivos por medio de el chat, pensé en esto para mandar el archivo:

```
file = open("file.txt", "rb")
content = file.readlines(1024)
sock.send(content)
file.close()
```

y esto para recibir:

```
file = open("file.txt", "wb")
file.write(sock.recv(1024))
file.close()
```

(estos no son los códigos reales, es solo son lo básico para no tener que complicarme tanto escribiendo aquí)
el problema es que la variable `content` es una lista y no se puede mandar por el socket.

Comment: Realmente no estan enviando un archivo sino estas enviando el texto que contiene el archivo

Comment: Si realmente quieres enviar un archivo lo tienes hacer es convertirlo en binario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si solo vas a enviar el archivo, no tiene mucho sentido que uses `readlines`, aparte de ineficiente por crear una lista y tener que iterar sobre el archivo buscando los finales de línea, no aporta nada realmente.

Para enviar el archivo podemos simplemente abrirlo en mosenddo binario y con un `while` iterar para leerlo en fragmentos usando `read`. Un ejemplo muy simplificado de un servidor que envía un archivo a un cliente podría ser:
send

**Servidor:**

```
import socket


HOST = '' 
PORT = 50007
CHUNK_SIZE = 5 * 1024
FILE = "example.txt"

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        with open(FILE, 'rb') as f:
            data = f.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
            while data:
                conn.sendall(data)
                data = f.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
```

**Cliente:**

```
import socket


HOST = ''
PORT = 50007
CHUNK_SIZE = 5 * 1024
FILE = "example2.txt"

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))

    with open(FILE, "wb") as f:        
        chunk = s.recv(CHUNK_SIZE)

        while chunk:
            f.write(chunk)
            chunk = s.recv(CHUNK_SIZE)
```

Si se usa Python >= 3.5 puedes usar [`socket.socket.sendfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendfile) que es considerablemente más eficiente si el sistema operativo implementa `os.sendfile`, en caso contrario usará `send`:

```
import socket


HOST = '' 
PORT = 50007
FILE = "example.txt"

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        with open(FILE, 'rb') as f:
            conn.sendfile(f)
```

Comment: y que pongo de lado del cliente en el ejemplo de python 3.5 o más?

Comment: @binario_newbie puedes usar el mismo cliente.

Comment: @FJSevilla, por que se pone este valor `CHUNK_SIZE = 5 * 1024`

Comment: @AngelJudathAlvarez es solo el tamaño de los fragmentos en los que dividimos el archivo y que enviamos por el socket. En este caso son 5 Kb (1024 bytes * 5). Es solo un tamaño razonable, pero que puedes variar. El valor óptimo depende del caso, varios factores pueden influir, desde el sistema operativo, red, disco, características del procesador, etc

Answer (score 1):

Intenta enviando cada posición de la lista.

Puedes usar `len()` para ello o guiarte del siguiente código:

```
def mysend(self, msg):
    totalsent = 0
    while totalsent < MSGLEN:
        sent = self.sock.send(msg[totalsent:])
        if sent == 0:
            raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
        totalsent = totalsent + sent
```

Comment: Para más información puedes encontrar este ejemplo en https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html#socket-howto