# Archivo corrupto al enviarlo por socket en python

Tags: python-3.x, socket

Estoy tratando de enviar una imagen por socket en python, no me da ningún error pero el archivo esta corrupto.

Aqui esta el codigo del servidor:

```
cliente.send(bytes("*descargarArchivo", "utf-8"));

print("Introduzca el nombre del archivo");
nombreDescargar = input(">>>");

cliente.send(bytes(nombreDescargar,"utf-8"));


f = open("recibido.jpg", "wb");

tamanoArchivo = cliente.recv(1024).decode("utf-8").strip();

if tamanoArchivo:
    print(str(tamanoArchivo));

if tamanoArchivo.isdigit():
    cliente.send(bytes("OK", "utf-8"));

buffer = 0;

with open("recibido.jpg", "wb") as archi:
        # Nos preparamos para recibir el archivo
        # con la longitud específica
        while buffer <= int(tamanoArchivo):
            data = cliente.recv(1);
            if not len(data):
                # Si no recibimos datos
                # salimos del bucle
                print("Ya no hay data")
                break
            # Escribimos cada byte en el archivo
            # y aumentamos en uno el buffer
            archi.write(data)
            buffer += 1


        if buffer == int(tamanoArchivo):
            print("Archivo descargado con éxito")

        else:
            print("Ocurrió un error/Archivo incompleto")          
        archi.close();
```

Y aqui el codigo del cliente:

```
   elif mensaje == "*descargarArchivo":
        nombreArchivo = linea.recv(1024).decode("utf-8");

       # f = open("Descargas/"+nombreArchivo, "rb");

        #ENVIAR LA CANTIDAD DE BYTES DEL ARCHIVO
        with open("Descargas/"+nombreArchivo, "rb") as fo:
            buffer = fo.read();

        if os.path.isfile("Descargas/"+nombreArchivo):
            #enviar cantidad bytes
            linea.send(bytes(str(len(buffer)), "utf-8") )

            mensajeOk = linea.recv(20).decode("utf-8");

            if mensajeOk == "OK":

                for byte in buffer:
                    linea.send(bytes(byte));

        else:
            print("El arhivo no se encuentra");
```

Alguna idea de porque sucede esto?

Comment: Asegurate de que tienes la cabecera de codificacion utf-8 en tu archivo .py,  de lo contrario es muy probable que te encuentres con errores de ese tipo, ya que si,  tu especificas que los bytes enviados deben ser codificados usando charset utf-8, pero si como tal no le dices a python que tiene que usar ese encoding es como decirle a un gringo que hable chino. Sin haberselo enseñado a hablar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema clave está en:

```
buffer = fo.read();

# .....

for byte in buffer:
    linea.send(bytes(byte))
```

- Tu lees el archivo en modo binario (`rb`), esto hace que `read` retorne ya un objeto bytes:

  ```
  buffer = b"123"
  ```
- En Python 3 cuando se itera sobre una cadena de bytes se retorna el valor entero para ese byte (`int`) (0-255). Por ejemplo:

  ```
  for byte in b"123":
      print(byte)

  49
  50
  51
  ```
- Cuando haces `bytes(byte)` lo que haces es inicializar un objeto `bytes` con `byte` numero de bytes con valor 0:

  ```
   >>> bytes(1)
   b'\x00'

   >>> bytes(2)
   b'\x00\x00'

   >>> bytes(3)
   b'\x00\x00\x00'
  ```

Ya la hemos liado parda... tu quieres enviar `b"1"` y envías:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

que es lo que retorna `bytes(49),` tu archivo queda como un bonito archivo repletito `b'\x00`.

Alguien puede que esté pensando ¡pero que * es ésto!. A mi no me gusta tampoco este comportamiento, de hecho hay un PEP pendiente (aplazada para Python 3.9 a día de hoy) para modificar la API heredada de los primeros tiempos de Python, especialmente ahora que nos hemos deshecho de Python 2:

- [PEP 467 -- Minor API improvements for binary sequences](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0467/#discourage-use-of-current-zero-initialised-sequence-behaviour)

Para solucionarlo puedes hacer varias cosas:

- Usar el método `int.to_bytes()`

  ```
  linea.send(int_byte.to_bytes(1, sys.byteorder))
  ```
- Usar slicing:

  ```
  for i in range(len(buffer)):
      linea.send(buffer[i: i + 1])
  ```
- Usar `struct`:

  ```
  import struct

  for byte in struct.unpack(f"{len(buffer)}c", buffer):
      linea.send(byte)
  ```

Usando tu código modificando lo mínimo tu idea original, este sería un ejemplo reproducible:

**`server.py`**

```
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 65432

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    cliente, addr = s.accept()
    with cliente:
        print('Conectado con ', addr)
        cliente.send(b"*descargarArchivo")
        nombre_descargar = input("Introduzca el nombre del archivo\n>>>")
        cliente.send(nombre_descargar.encode("utf-8"))
        tamaño_archivo = cliente.recv(1024).decode("utf-8").strip()

        try:
            n_bytes = int(tamaño_archivo)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            cliente.send(b"OK")
            buffer = 0
            with open(nombre_descargar, "wb") as archi:
                while n_bytes > buffer:
                    data = cliente.recv(1)
                    if not len(data):
                        print("Ya no hay data")
                        break
                    archi.write(data)
                    buffer += 1
                if buffer == n_bytes:
                    print("Archivo descargado con éxito")
                else:
                    print("Ocurrió un error/Archivo incompleto")
```

**`client.py`**

```
import os
import socket
import struct



HOST = ''
PORT = 65432

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as linea:
    linea.connect((HOST, PORT))
    mensaje = linea.recv(100).decode("utf-8")
    if mensaje == "*descargarArchivo":
        nombre_archivo = linea.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        path = os.path.join("Descargas/", nombre_archivo)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            with open(path, "rb") as fo:
                buffer = fo.read()
                linea.send(str(len(buffer)).encode("utf-8"))
                mensaje_ok = linea.recv(20).decode("utf-8")
                if mensaje_ok == "OK":
                    for byte in struct.unpack(f"{len(buffer)}c", buffer):
                        linea.send(byte)
        else:
            print("El arhivo no se encuentra")
```

Esto sin modificar tu implementación inicial demasiado, lo conveniente sería no enviar byte a byte y evitar cargar el archivo en memoria, un archivo de 2Kb no es problema pero uno de 5Gb ya es otra cosa...

- [¿Como puedo mandar un archivo por un socket?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/187700/15089)